# pickle HMAC validation - how to upload pickle without deserializing?

Tags: security, pickle, hmac

Python's pickle module includes a [warning](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) on attack vector that can be mitigated by validation with hmac hashing. In order to validate, one can hash the object after pickling and compare after uploading into a separate notebook and re-pickling for hmac inspection.

Part of the challenge is that when pickling, say a dictionary that includes values of function addresses, those addresses may not be durable between notebooks. So in order to validate with hmac would need to compare hashes of the pickled dictionary, meaning in the second notebook the hmac hash would need to be inspected before deserializing with pickle.

Is it possible to upload a pickled object without deserializing?

```
import pickle
import hmac, hashlib

def function():
  return True

dictionary = \
{'function' : function}

pickled_dictionary = \
pickle.dumps(dictionary) 

secret_key = '1234'

hmaced_dictionary = \
hmac.new(secret_key.encode(), 
         pickled_dictionary, 
         hashlib.sha256
        ).hexdigest()

with open('filename.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
  pickle.dump(dictionary, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
  
#________________

#now in seperate notebook we want to validate the dictionary contents

import pickle
import hmac, hashlib

import pickle
with open('filename.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
  dictionary_upload = pickle.load(handle)

pickled_dicitonary_upload = \
pickle.dumps(dictionary_upload) 

hmaced_dictionary_upload = \
hmac.new(secret_key.encode(), pickled_dicitonary_upload, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

#unfortunately we can't validate with hmac
#since the functions will have a diferent memory address in new notebook
hmaced_dictionary_upload != hmaced_dictionary

#________________

#we could circumvent this obstacle 
#if possible to upload and hmac the pickled dictionary
#without deserializing
#couldn't figure out how to upload with pickle without deserializing
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is insecure: you need to check the hmac *before* pickling, not after.

Typically this is done by storing the hmac it separately from the pickled blob (or in a header).  This way you can recompute the hmac on the pickled blob and compare it to the expected one *before unpickling*.